# Changing AAD accessTokenAcceptedVersion does not result in token version change

Tags: azure-active-directory

I created a new app registration for an app service resource and the accessTokenAcceptedVersion was set to 2 by default (or may be due to my choices). Some clients got an access token for this resource and is being potentially cached on that client.

Later I changed the accessTokenAcceptedVersion to null (i.e. default 1). Now those clients fail to authenticate to the resource (rightfully so) given they have a cached v2 token.

The client in this case is an azure function using the AzureServiceTokenProvider library for getting & caching tokens. So I tried various ways to invalidate the cache involving :

- Restarting the function
- Waiting out for 1 day (the token expiration time)
- Making changes to the app registration
- Unfortunately Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken doesn't seem to work for managed identities.

But I'm still getting a V2 token. What can be done to invalidate this cache or to force a V1 token somehow? I'm trying to do this without any code change currently. But can deploy a change if needed at all.

On other machines/infra I'm able to get a V1 token for the same resource using the different identity. As per my understanding, the token version purely only depends on accessTokenAcceptedVersion. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below points:

1. If you have changed the accessTokenAcceptedVersion to ‘null’ value, it may also permit v2.0 tokens – It is an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/19304) on AAD’s side. It also depends on the way the app is registered. The difference is that:

- If it was done using Azure Portal, then the 'accessTokenAcceptedVersion' field of manifest is set to 'null'
- If it was done in the App Registration portal(https://apps.dev.microsoft.com), then it may point to version ‘2.0’

2. Also check :

   The v1 authorization endpoint : `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/authorize?`

   The v1 token endpoint :  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/token`

   Try to change the authority and instance to v1 endpoint in the code and also wherever it is used in the code.

   See  [Microsoft identity platform access tokens - Microsoft identity platform |   Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#what-app-is-a-token-for)

   Both v1 and v2.0 endpoints have their own parameters separately. The v2.0 endpoint expect the ‘scope’ parameter in the request, whereas v1 endpoint expect `‘resource’.` So do check the scopes for the api you are referring to and change the code accordingly.
3. If you still get v2.0 tokens, you must clear the cache of the client application calling your API otherwise until the token has expired, token would be taken from the cache, and would still be a v2.0 token. For that, you may try to call `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` (in the client while calling you Web API) to force the refresh.

**Reference:**

[Wrong version of access token (got Azure AD V1 instead of V2)  GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/575)